# Disable "More Choices" option on User account control:

Tags: uac, more

I want to hide "More Choices" in User Account Control when I install or run the Apps that means allows Administrator password only,..

[User Account Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mTW7.png)

Comment: Probably not. Microsoft does not provide individual customizations for this.

Comment: I think disabling fast user switching via group policy will remove some  cached user accounts info displayed here, but it won't completely get rid of the "more choices" button.

Comment: More Choices does not mean you can then run an install using an account that doesn't have the necessary permissions. It it based on the idea that Windows supports and allows multiple admin accounts, locally, or by an associated directory service. I think that, instead of what you wrote, you may actually want to know how (if it is possible) to allow ONLY the local admin account to be used in an elevation/UAC prompt. But, the way you do this is to only have one admin on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm turning this into an answer, because I think it addresses your true question and answers it:

**More Choices** does not mean you can then run an install using an account that doesn't have the necessary permissions. It it based on the idea that Windows supports and allows multiple admin accounts, locally or via an associated directory service.

So long as you are dealing with local accounts only and this computer is not attached to a domain, the way to accomplish what you want is to have only one admin account on your computer. While this will not remove the More Choices option from these prompts, it will make them meaningless without removing the underlying, and integral, function they are based upon.